# Frequent Subgraph Mining in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I wanted to do Frequent Subgraph Mining(FSM) in Neo4j. I have done the same in R using the subgraphMining package. I have been reading through the book

> Practical Graph Mining with R Nagiza F. Samatova, William Hendrix,
>   John Jenkins, Kanchana Padmanabhan, Arpan Chakraborty July 15, 2013 by
>   Chapman and Hall/CRC

I was interested in using the SLEUTH algorithm in Neo4j as the number of graphs from which I would have to extract the Frequent Subgraphs would be very large.

My requirement is not specific to any implementation language and am be interested in implementation of FSM that has been implemented in any language.

FSM implementation using Pregel on Single Graph.

[Frequent Subgraph Mining Based
on Pregel](https://watermark.silverchair.com/bxv118.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAdMwggHPBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggHAMIIBvAIBADCCAbUGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMG4IFSo7ickU3pPrTAgEQgIIBhqsyL_4ZfyCQj9qHP16HVBS4sTLDbPoJr95ZS7-zhSIxQUewNnUNDU6B2OOfj8zBeMNQytJ2HOya7Mx8z3sM8S1AZQPySTbgf8NimJjb4ag5_BREc7l9T_sFxoJdzDMYAIjF-0locHs6-XXwK9Z7Oxf2laIygR-vkPE1ZrIPzd36ufpOdQtxP-WjAMy4RmuaNB8RyKaJQ4XYblBK9sr3NBTsWKsddwDc-UdAF-TQ5gjpQ4qxJz02AbyMN0S9Jl3StA1AKgu3PlbqKubPeNxBgWIk6CVl77E2M4_o7qhDcEFKPQizxfzO2ddGXZzUZCOerxK4AODsq2qQUPI_lxVxZwh6rTIaPlcPfT_BP7O8nbnMt69rc-LMGnV5FxED4DNP0azMOZUoHujpcMTOnB2r8KEDHnhJSUkm0kjONauKwAjDh3IW7_h7UPM6TfGDZZEbveNzj30C-RY_KA5KabJS9ItoQMK2IsSMO_GZmBhCqvWHVrAh6EyVtcqpBfna5cd6pCdd4OGzAg)

Comment: I've been looking into that recently as well and came up to Gradoop : https://github.com/dbs-leipzig/gradoop which can run atop Neo4j.

Comment: @Chirstophe Willemsen Thank you for the response. Not very aware of Gradoop. Does Gradoop provide FSM out of the box?

Comment: @Bonson Gradoop integrates a variant of the GSpan FSM algorithm for graph transactions (i.e. finding frequent patterns in a set of graphs). Check https://github.com/dbs-leipzig/gradoop/tree/master/gradoop-flink/src/main/java/org/gradoop/flink/algorithms/fsm for the source code and have a look at the test. The implementation is discussed in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01910 Ping me if you have questions.

Comment: @s1ck Thank you for the response. I also looked at GraphX and Giraph. Saw Pregel and see that it has an implementation of FSM on single graph detailed at a paper updated in the main question. I understand that Gradoop is the only one to have implemented FSM out of the box on multigraphs. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: @Bonson If your definition of multigraph is "having multiple graphs" then your understanding is correct. And it is worth to note that Gradoop gives you a property graph abstraction on a generic distributed dataflow system.

Comment: @s1ck Thank you for your direction. I shall delve into and implement using Gradoop and see further. In case you feel that any specific documentation that would be helpful then kindly do let me know of the same. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Bonson You're welcome. There is no official documentation. However, the  README contains a few links to recent talks and publications. Also there is a submodule called gradoop-examples in which you find examples for FSM (class DIMSpanRunner) and other Gradoop operators / algorithms. Feel free to reach out via GitHub issues, PRs, twitter (@kc1s).